# Is it possible to add a GenericClass<SubClass> to a List<GenericClass<Base>> in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have three classes in my C# project: `GenericClass<T>`, where T may be a `BaseClass` or descendant `SubClass`.

I need to create a list of `GenericClass<BaseClass>` that accepts either `GenericClass<BaseClass>`, or descendants of `BaseClass` in the generic. I've attempted to do this by creating a `List<GenericClass<BaseClass>>` like below:

```
List<GenericClass<BaseClass>> list = new List<GenericClass<BaseClass>>();
GenericClass<SubClass> test = new GenericClass<SubClass>();
list.Add( test );
```

C# refuses to perform this operation, telling me that a `GenericClass<SubClass>` is not a `GenericClass<BaseClass>`.Why is this? This seems counterintuitive, as a `SubClass` is a form of `BaseClass`.

`GenericClass<T>` is designed to be a registerable type that game scripts may use to encapsulate custom game object types that descend from a base object. Is there a way to achieve this without using reflection? `BaseClass` contains methods with code common to all objects, so it cannot be made into an interface.

Comment: how these classes are defined?

Comment: The only thing I forgot to mention is that `GenericClass` is defined as:

`public class GenericClass< T > where T : BaseClass, new()`

Comment: [What is the purpose of this?](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Just because `SubClass` inherits from `BaseClass` it does not mean that `GenericClass<SubClass>` inherits from `GenericClass<BaseClass>`. It does not.

Comment: You say, "`BaseClass` contains methods with code common to all objects, so it cannot be made into an interface", but that doesn't follow in my mind. Why can't you make an interface?

Comment: No. The usual way to kludge around this sort of thing is to give GenericClass a non-generic base class -- often abstract -- and move everything you can up to there, leaving the generic to introduce only the members that must have `T` in their prototypes. That can buy you an awful lot in many of the cases where you might want to do this. I can't say if your case is one of them, though.

Comment: @MikeNielsen, any answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this for *interfaces*, not for a concrete implementation.

If your classes are defined as follows:

```
public interface IGeneric<out T> where T : BaseClass, new() { }
public class GenericClass<T> : IGeneric<T> where T : BaseClass, new() { }

public interface IBase { }
public class BaseClass { }
public class SubClass : BaseClass { }
```

You can do this:

```
List<IGeneric<BaseClass>> list = new List<IGeneric<BaseClass>>();
GenericClass<SubClass> test = new GenericClass<SubClass>();
list.Add(test);
```

Note that the lists generic argument is `IGeneric`, not `GenericClass`.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a base class and make your `GenericClass<T>` inherits from this base class :

```
public class GenericClass { }

public class GenericClass<T> : GenericClass { }
```

So now you can create a `List<GenericClass>`

```
var list = new List<GenericClass>();
list.Add(new GenericClass<BaseClass>());
list.Add(new GenericClass<SubClass>());
```